# Static CSS files being generated by JS isn't

Tags: javascript, theme

I'm using default/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml to add CSS and JS. In developer mode, CSS is being added to static files but JS and files are not.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
            <link src="js/menu.js"></link>
            <link src="js/iehover-fix.js"></link>
    </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My /web folder was not in the correct folder.
It should be themename/default/web
I had themename/default/Magento_Theme/web

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `script` tag and specifying the module:

```
<script src="Magento_Theme::js/menu.js"/>
<script src="Magento_Theme::js/iehover-fix.js"/>
```

Comment: I tried this but Magento_Theme:: was not rendering a path